# ValueInjecter in Wp7 or something similar?

Tags: windows-phone-7, valueinjecter

I am wondering if you can use [ValueInjecter](https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) or something similar in a Windows Phone 7?

Comment: I don't think a SL version exist for ValueInjector. If you don't mind a different framework you can use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) which includes a WP7.1 lib.

Comment: there is a silverlight version of the valueinjecter (https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/releases/view/60311), plus you can always grab the code